# like operator using index in sql

Tags: sql

I am using a SP to filter data based on location and name.I am new to index part. I wrote a SP like below to get data from table

```
create procedure [dbo].[Seach_University]
(
 @Search varchar(100),
 @SerLocation varchar(100)
)
as begin
declare @x varchar(100) = '"'+@search+'*"',
        @y varchar(100) = '"'+@SerLocation +'*"'

select * from tbl_Groups where contains(Group_Name ,@x ) and  contains(Location,@y)
end
```

This code work great when i send to keywords. Problem comes when i send only one value (either @SerLocation  or @search) data is not coming i.e., when null is going.

can any one help me, in such way that even if null value goes, it should work like below code

```
select * from tbl_Groups where Group_Name like '%'+@Search+'%' and  Location like '%'+@SerLocation+'%'
```

Comment: Indexes will generally only work on LIKE conditions that are *anchored* to the start, such as `'FOO%'`. Once you add in `'%FOO'` the trivial index is out.

Comment: so i cannot use index for like this search? or i have to like below answer by @Nihat

Comment: That is correct, Group_name index won't be used (Imagine someone told you to find list of people from phone book whose name contains 'al', you wouldnt be able to use the alphabetical order--in other words, the index of phone book, you would have to scan everything, index would work in similar fashion ) You can use either one I described below.

Comment: Thanq i will go with it then..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one query version

```
select * from tbl_Groups where 
(@search is not null and @serLocation is not null and 
    contains(Group_Name ,@x ) and  contains(Location,@y)) or 
(@search is not null and @serLocation is null and 
    contains(Group_Name ,@x ) ) or 
(@search is  null and @serLocation is not null and 
    contains(Location,@y))
```

Long version: You can add if  statements to your procedure body like so

```
if @search is not null and @serLocation is not null 
begin 
select * from tbl_Groups where contains(Group_Name ,@x ) and  contains(Location,@y)
end 

if @search is not null and @serLocation is  null 
begin 
select * from tbl_Groups where contains(Group_Name ,@x ) 
end 

if @search is  null and @serLocation is not null 
begin 
select * from tbl_Groups where  contains(Location,@y)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, I can do that, as like condition i want query in 1 or 2 line.